# ActiveMQMessageConsumer receives message only once in 5 seconds from Topic on Java

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm trying to receive hundreds of messages from Topic using [ActiveMQMessageConsumer](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.12.1/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQMessageConsumer.html) in Java. I add a MessageListener to handle the messages and for some reason I only get a message each 5 seconds. How can i configure this?
My code:

```
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

final Topic topic = session.createTopic(myTopic);
final MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(topic);
messageConsumer.receiveNoWait();

messageConsumer.setMessageListener(message -> {
       if (message != null) {
            try {
                System.out.println("A message received: "
                                           + ((TextMessage) message).getText()
                                           + "\n at: " + Instant.now());
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
Thread.sleep(500000);
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. Well, given you start your connection. It can easily handle thousands messages within seconds. There has to be something else - are you really publishing hundreds of messages to the topic after your message listener has started and not only 1/5 s? Is there a non standard ActiveMQ setup? (Network of brokers, scheduled messages or what not)?

Comment: Thanks, @PetterNordlander messages are get produced quick enough, but there is a possibility that either message persistence or something else bugs the Consumer or the Topic. Back to investigating..

Comment: Are you persisting into backup tapes? ;-) tried your code and it litteray works with 1000 persistent msgs/s. At least. So, yeah, look elsewhere.

Comment: @PetterNordlander thanks a lot for your input! It was kind of frustrating to be looking through all the activemq lib code to find that wasn't even there. So it was nice to have someone to confirm that the code is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue was in the part of the app that produced messages and arranged the Topic. Changing it and leaving the Consumer part as is fixed the issue.